# Database email not working in sql server 2008, but works in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I executed following script on SQL Server 2012 and SQL Server 2008. I received an email which is sent from SQL Server 2012, but not from SQL Server 2008.

```
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_account_sp  
@account_name = 'my_account_name',
@email_address = 'my-email-address@gmail.com',
@display_name = 'Mail From SQL Server',    
@description = 'sending email via gmail account',
@mailserver_name = 'smtp.gmail.com',    
@port = 587,
@username = 'my-email-address@gmail.com',
@password = 'my-password',    
@enable_ssl = 1

EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profile_sp
   @profile_name = 'my email profile',
   @description = 'Profile used for XXX emails.'

EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profileaccount_sp
@profile_name = 'my email profile',
@account_name = 'my_account_name',
@sequence_number = 1 ;


EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_principalprofile_sp
@principal_name = 'public',
@profile_name = 'my email profile',
@is_default = 1 ;

exec msdb.dbo.sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
exec msdb.dbo.sp_configure 'Database Mail XPs', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
@profile_name = 'my email profile', 
@recipients = 'another-gmail@gmail.com', 
@subject = 'Mail Test', 
@body = 'Mail Sent Successfully', 
@body_format = 'text'
```

Getting this error when using SQL Server 2008 for Database Mail.

```
The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure.(Sending Mail using Account 6 (2014-04-05T11:39:19). Exception Message: Could not connect to mail server. (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 74.125.25.109:587).)
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Could be a firewall issue?

Comment: Like @dean stated, but not at the Server level.  Check your SQLMail settings and make sure the Credentials used to connect to the mail server are correct, and have not been Policy'd to a locked state.  I usually setup the Mail Account to not abide by the network Policy password retention and put in a 32 character length mix-mode password.  Start from SQLMail and work your way out.

Comment: Are these on different hosts or just different SQL Instances? Can you ping the SMTP server from the failing server? Can you `TELNET <smtpserver> 25` from the failing server? (firewall test)

Answer (score 0):

I don't there is any issue in the script. Mostly probably issue mail server profile that is "my email profile". Compare the profile which you created in 2008 and 20012 specially mail server IP and credential . From there you may get hints.